# bash if statement stops working when run as sudo

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Here is a very simple bash script.

```
#/usr/bin/env bash
set -e

containerName=$1
if [ "$containerName" == "" ]; then
  echo "Hello"
fi
```

The expected behavior should be if I call the script with no arguments, then it prints "Hello"; otherwise, it does nothing.

If I call the script like this `./test.sh` it works fine.

However, if I call it with sudo, like `sudo ./test.sh` the command fails with the error:

```
./test.sh: 5: [: unexpected operator
```

What am I doing wrong here? Why should sudo modify the behavior of my program in this way?

Comment: put set -x on the second line and what what happens. You will be able to see what the shell is doing and figure out what went wrong.

Comment: What is the default shell of root. Does it use the first line during sudo or roots defaults. echo $SHELL to find out.

Comment: Apparently its because I am missing the ! in my first line of my bash file.

Comment: Without the `!`, `sudo` uses `/bin/sh`, which doesn't guarantee that `==` is recognized as a valid operator with `[`. Always use `=` with `[`.

Comment: Better yet, just use `[ -z "$containerName" ]`; it's shorter and portable.